# If statements Evaluations

Tags: java

Using the code below I get this result even though I put in a number that is greater than 18.
run:
How old are you? 21
You have not reached the age of Majority yet!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)

I am new to java and trying to self learn can anybody help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Chapter8 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
        // TODO code application logic here

        //Excercise 15
        System.out.print("How old are you? ");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        if (x > 18){
            System.out.println("You have not reached the age of Majority yet!");
        }else {
            System.out.println("You have reached the age of Majority!");
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code currently reads "if the age is greater than 18 (ie 19 or more) then they are not of age".

I think you meant `x < 18`

Answer (score 0):

Should be the other way around:

```
if (x < 18){
       System.out.println("You have not reached the age of Majority yet!");
}else {
        System.out.println("You have reached the age of Majority!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a statement that only will print a line if x > 18. You should make an else if statement to finish the statement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
    // TODO code application logic here

    //Excercise 15
    System.out.print("How old are you? ");
    int x = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    if (x > 18){
        System.out.println("You have not reached the age of Majority yet!");
    }
    else if (x <= 17){
        System.out.println("You have reached the age of Majority!");
    }
```

}

Comment: I answered your question with the silly mistake. I think you mean that (x <= 17) should print "You have not reached the age of majority yet!" and (x > 18) should print "You have reached the age of majority!"